# How to express the differentiation of an antisymmetric matrix (the HFB pairing field)?

Tags: nuclear-physics

I'm trying to wrap my head around the differentiation of antisymmetric matrices in the context of [Hartree-Fock-Bogoliubov](http://www.fuw.edu.pl/~dobaczew/BCS50-28w/node3.html) (HFB) mean-field theory (see also e.g. Ring & Schuck, Blaizot & Ripka, etc.).

The HFB pairing energy is defined in terms of the two-body matrix element $\bar v_{abcd}$, the pairing tensor $\kappa$ and its conjugate $\kappa^*$ (treated as separate degrees of freedom): $$E[\kappa,\kappa^*] = \frac{1}{4}\sum_{abcd}\bar v_{abcd}\kappa^*_{ab}\kappa_{cd}.$$  The pairing tensors are antisymmetric ($\kappa_{ij} = -\kappa_{ji}$) as is the matrix element ($\bar v_{abcd} = - \bar v_{abdc}$).

The pairing field is *defined* as $$\Delta_{ij} \equiv \frac{\partial E}{\partial \kappa^*_{ij}} = \frac{1}{2}\sum_{cd}\bar v_{ijcd}\kappa_{cd},$$ with very little explanation given for the second inequality.

(1) Does the above equality come from the anti-symmetry of $\kappa^*$?  I can make it work by noting that $\kappa_{ba} = -\kappa_{ab}$ before taking the necessary derivatives (claiming, using antisymmetry, that $\partial\kappa_{ab}/\partial\kappa_{cd} = \delta_{ac}\delta_{bd}-\delta_{bc}\delta_{ad}$), yielding $$\Delta_{ij} = \frac{1}{4}\sum_{abcd}\bar v_{abcd}\kappa_{cd} \left(\delta_{ia}\delta_{jb}-\delta_{ib}\delta_{ja}\right) = \frac{1}{2}\sum_{cd}\bar v_{abcd}\kappa_{cd}.$$  But I haven't seen it written down anywhere.

(2) This leads to a problem: how can I then write $E$ in the following way (ignoring the $\kappa$ degrees of freedom)?  $$E = \sum_{ab}\frac{\partial E}{\partial \kappa^*_{ab}}\kappa^*_{ab} = \frac{1}{2}\sum_{abcd}\bar v_{abcd}\kappa^*_{ab}\kappa_{cd} \neq E!$$ I can make an argument that, because $\kappa^*$ is anti-symmetric, only $a>b$ are independent degrees of freedom, introducing the required extra factor of $1/2$, but is this the right way to think about things?  I'm trying to put everything on a firm foundation.